# hide menu from user who is not in particular role

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to hide Article menuitem , when user is not logged in , 
code in master page is as below.

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Articles_List.aspx" Text="Articles" Value="Articles"/>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ItemsCategory.aspx" Text="Items" Value="Items"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Gallery.aspx" Text="Gallery" Value="Gallery"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Account/Register.aspx" Text="Registration" Value="Registration"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About us" Value="About"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

i wrote code, but it's not working.

```
LoginView lv;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lv = (LoginView)Master.FindControl("HeadLoginView");
    if (!lv.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        NavigationMenu.Items.RemoveAt(1);
    }   
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?
can you show, how is this code not working ?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
code behind Site.master.cs

Comment: do you happen to be using MasterPage.. ? the MasterPage code will execute before any other pages so you need to check and set the menu items there

Comment: yes i'm using master page

Comment: Also I would Default all the menus items to Visible = False vs trying to remove them and if IsAuthenticated, then set the menu Items Visible property to True.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: i didn't get you. what are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this 

<%if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){ %>
        <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home "/>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Articles_List.aspx" Text="Articles" Value="Articles" />
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ItemsCategory.aspx" Text="Items" Value="Items" />
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Gallery.aspx" Text="Gallery" Value="Gallery" />
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Account/Register.aspx" Text="Registration" Value="Registration" />
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About us" Value="About" />
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
        <%}else{ %>
            <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home "/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ItemsCategory.aspx" Text="Items" Value="Items" />
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Gallery.aspx" Text="Gallery" Value="Gallery" />
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Account/Register.aspx" Text="Registration" Value="Registration" />
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About us" Value="About" />
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
<%} %>
```